# Parse error with simple jison grammar

Tags: javascript, parsing, grammar, jison

I am trying to create a simple script language. For the beginning i just wanted stuff like

```
i = 5;
i += 3;
out(i);
```

So i created the following grammar for jison:

```
%lex
%%

\s+                  { /* ignore */ }

"="                  { return '='; }
"+="                 { return '+='; }
"-="                 { return '-='; }
"*="                 { return '*='; }
"/="                 { return '/='; }

"."                  { return '.'; }
"("                  { return '('; }
")"                  { return ')'; }
"{"                  { return '{'; }
"}"                  { return '}'; }

[0-9]+               { return 'NUMBER'; }
[A-Z]*               { return 'CHAR_SEQUENCE'; }

<<EOF>>              { return 'EOF'; }

/lex

%%

Program
    : StatementList EOF
        {
            return function()
            {
                for(var i = 0; i < $1.length; i++)
                {
                    $1[i]();
                }
            };
        }
    ;

StatementList
    : StatementList Statement
        { $$ = $1.concat($2); }
    |
        { $$ = []; }
    ;

Statement
    : AssignStatement
    | VariableOutput
    ;

Operator
    : "="
        { $$ = function(left, right) { left.set(right); }; }
    | "+="
        { $$ = function(left, right) { left.add(right); }; }
    | "-="
        { $$ = function(left, right) { left.remove(right); }; }
    | "*="
        { $$ = function(left, right) { left.multiplicate(right); }; }
    | "/="
        { $$ = function(left, right) { left.divide(right); }; }
    ;


VariableOutput
    : 'out(' CHAR_SEQUENCE ')' ';'
        {
            $$ = function()
            {
                var t = new Tellraw("Output: ");
                t.extra.push(vars[$1].toTellrawExtra());
                t.tell(new Entities.Player("@a"));
            };
        }
    ;

AssignStatement
    : CHAR_SEQUENCE Operator CHAR_SEQUENCE ';'
        {
            $$ = function()
            {
                Util.assert(typeof vars[$3] != 'undefined', "Unknown identifier '"+$3+"'");

                if(typeof vars[$1] == 'undefined')
                    vars[$1] = vars[$3].constructor.call();

                $2(vars[$1], vars[$3]);
            };
        }
    | CHAR_SEQUENCE Operator '"' CHAR_SEQUENCE '"' ';'
        {
            $$ = function()
            {
                if(typeof vars[$1] == 'undefined')
                    vars[$1] = new Runtime.String($3);

                $2(vars[$1], $3);
            };
        }
    | CHAR_SEQUENCE Operator NUMBER ';'
        {
            $$ = function()
            {
                if(typeof vars[$1] == 'undefined')
                    vars[$1] = new Runtime.Integer($3);

                $2(vars[$1], $3);
            };
        }
    ;
```

It generates the parser without complaining about the grammar. My problem is that when I do

```
parser.parse('i=5;out(i);')();
```

I get this error

```
Parse error on line 1:
i = 5;out(i);
^
Expecting '=', '+=', '-=', '*=', '/=', got 'CHAR_SEQUENCE'
```

This totally confuses me :/ there is no rule that expects an operator at first. The only rules expecting an operator are the AssignStatements but they all expect an CHAR_SQUENCE as first object.

Am i doing something wrong? Or why does it not work?
If you need any further information feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting `i` to be a `CHAR_SEQUENCE` but `CHAR_SEQUENCE` is `[A-Z]*`, which is to say, only capital letters. You probably wanted something like `[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*`. So the lexer is not recognizing `i` at all.

However, it is recognizing an empty `CHAR_SEQUENCE`. In `jison`, unlike `flex`, patterns which can match the empty string will do so, and should almost always be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that when you use

```
[A-Z]*               { return 'CHAR_SEQUENCE'; }
```

with `*` instead of `+` you are considering the empty string as a CHAR_SEQUENCE and then the parser is finding two CHAR_SEQUENCE instead of just one?